# Google Analytics | What are the differences between Custom Variables & User Defined?

Tags: google-analytics

Can I think about `User Defined` as just another slot of a `Custom Variable` (with a visitor level scope, and without a name) or it's totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. User defined variable is a visitor level custom var. However, User defined variable could be deprecated and would recommend you to us